# Can I use metadata to limit the choices in another metadata column?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, metadata

SP Foundation 2010, no developer rights, no SPD. Those are the limitations that are the mother(s) of invention.

We're categorizing a number of documents with a three level hierarchy.

```
 +Billing
 +----+Account
 |    +-----Address Update
 |    +-----Due date change
 +----+Inquiry
 |    +-----Request Duplicate Bill
 +----+Payments
      +-----Payment Options
      +-----Payment Locations
      +-----Average Bill Inf
```

We have three metadata columns to handle this information, each is set up as a checkbox choice column.

Here's what I'd like to do: assuming we've selected `Billing` as our primary category and `Account` as our secondary, I'd like the next choice menu to show ONLY `Address Update` and
`Due date change` instead of ALL the tertiary choices.

Is that doable with OOTB SharePoint Foundation 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Since its OOTB, try using Jquery (inside a content editor web part) in the List Forms where you hide the required elements based on selection.

Hoping your metadata wont be updated in which case, you may have to re-code the JS code.